# Setting up an email for a subdomain with google domains

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, email

I am currently running a website with an apache server. My domain is on Google domain and thus Google Domains is also running my DDNS for it. I know Google gives you 100 free email forwardings for the main website. Is there a way I can use a subdomain instead on the email forwardings so that I can make an email such as example@example.example.com?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1009/117811

Comment: @Goyllo Questions on other Stack Exchange sites aren't considered duplicates for this site, but it's OK to link to them as you did with a "See this...", or even to link to them in a new answer on this site that paraphrases an answer elsewhere (as long as it's not quoted verbatim or without attribution to the author).

Comment: Thank you dan, I am not exactly sure about that, hence I did not flag it for duplicate. Thank you for the information:)